# Python, Calling a function again based on input from user

Tags: python

I'm trying to get back to the roll_die function within take_turn function after the user enters "y", then continue adding value to turn_score variable.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance, here's my code so far:

```
import random
def roll_die():
    roll_value = random.randint(1,6)
    return roll_value

def take_turn(is_human_turn):
    roll_die()
    roll = roll_die()
    turn_score = 0
    turn_score = turn_score + roll

    if is_human_turn:
        print("total so far:",turn_score)
        input("roll again? y/n ")
        if input == "y":
            roll_die()
        # Trying to get back to the roll_die func w/in take_turn func
        #  and continue adding value to turn_score

    return turn_score

take_turn(True)
```

Comment: You don't capture the return value of `roll_die()`.  Do `turn_score += roll_die()` instead

Comment: Wouldn't you need to save the result of `input` call? `myinput = input('...')`

Comment: `inValue = input("roll again? y/n ")
        if inValue == "y":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to:

1. Gather the 3 first lines of `take_turn()` function into `turn_score = roll_die()`
2. Use while loop to roll again until user enters something different from "y"
3. Add the value returned by `roll_die()` to `turn_score`
4. Do something with the value returned by `take_turn()` (otherwise do not return anything)

Here is my full code solution:

```
import random

def roll_die():
    roll_value = random.randint(1,6)
    return roll_value

def take_turn(is_human_turn):
    turn_score = roll_die()
    while is_human_turn:
        print("total so far:", turn_score)
        if input("roll again? y/n ") == "y":
            turn_score += roll_die()
        else:
            is_human_turn = False
    return turn_score

result = take_turn(True)
```